# How can I create email accounts on my web server?

Tags: domains, email, ubuntu, email-address

I'm wondering how to create an `info@domain.com` or any other email account (e.g., `john@domain.com`, `ann@domain.com`). What should I do?

I have my domains in GoDaddy, but I would like to not pay for creating emails accounts.

I have my sites on a server with Ubuntu + Apache as the web server.

I don't have cPanel in my server.

Comment: Please narrow down your question once you made some head way as currently as it stands the answer given would have to be a full blown tutorial which is unlikely to be answered or expecting far to much in one question.

Comment: @bybe I think I covered the basics.

Answer (score 2):

As [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MailServer) Ubuntu help document states:

> Setting up an email server is a difficult process involving a number
>   of different programs, each of which needs to be properly configured.

First you'll want to setup a Mail Transfer Agent (MTA), choosing either the default [Postfix](http://www.postfix.org/) or [exim4](http://www.exim.org/). [This](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Postfix) guide will explain how to install and configure Postfix.

Next you'll want to add Mail Filtering to deal with spam and viruses. If you selected Postfix, then follow [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PostfixAmavisNew) guide.

Then setup a Mail Delivery Agent (MDA) to provide an IMAP and POP3 server that you can connect to with an email client. [Dovecot](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Dovecot) and [Courier](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Courier) are two common choices for Ubuntu - see those links for how to install and configure them.

After you install and configure the above, you'll need make sure the following ports are available to the public:

- IMAP: 143
- POP: 110
- SMTP: 25

After that, you'll need to configure your DNS at GoDaddy (if you're not running a DNS server yourself). [Here](http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/7924/adding-or-editing-mx-records?locale=en) is an article on adding and editing MX records there. You'll also need to make sure you have CNAME records for POP, IMAP, and SMTP. [Here](http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/7921/adding-or-editing-cname-records?locale=en) is a guide on how to add and edit CNAME records there.

Last but not least, you'll want to make sure you have [Reverse DNS](http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/2585/what-is-reverse-dns) setup properly as that  can be used as a spam filter. [Here](http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/7926/adding-or-editing-spf-records) is an article on how to add and edit SPF Records there.

As you can see, running a mail server is not a simple task. I'd strongly suggest adding an email package to your domain at GoDaddy, and let them do all this work for you. You can search in Google for promotion codes to make this relatively inexpensive.

Comment: I have set up mail servers for my own use and have found they require more time to set up than a web server and require more monitoring. Not a project for the faint of heart.

Comment: @Paul More monitoring and vigilance for sure ;-)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Ubuntu on a server responding to a public IP address, it should either come with an email server or be able to [install one like Postfix](https://www.google.com/search?q=email%20server%20for%20ubuntu). Once you have a specific email program installed you should be able to look up documentation on how to set up email accounts. You may also have to have certain ports open or other settings in place.